# Exclude code from being built/compiled through gradle variants (Android)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to exclude code from being built/compiled through gradle build-variants ? My goal is not to obfuscate the code or having to different behaviours with build variables and if statements. I really want to exclude the code completely and not maintaining 2 code branches.

Sample:
I have a gradle file with 2 build variants:

```
buildTypes {
    versionWithCodeSnipped{

    }
    versionWithoutCodeSnipped{

    }
}
```

I have some Code I like to be excluded from built.

```
public void someMethod() {
    <someCode>

    <code snipped to be excluded in case of versionWithoutCodeSnipped>

    <someCode>
}
```

How to exclude the code above with build variants ?

Comment: Am I correct in reading your question that you would not be open to solutions that create a second copy of the method (or even just the subset that you want to exclude)?

Comment: Yes you are interpretating right. I would like to exclude code. If I would have a subset or different method, I would have to exclude that method in a higher in the code. R8 optimization would theoretically exlude unused code, which is not transparent (can't be trusted) to me. So I would like to remove code actively.

Comment: you can make a class delegate where will be a method with code snipped. and you can override delegate method behavior by build variants

Comment: @HeyAlex: Thanks. I do not understand. Can you give me a hint for 'override delegate method behavior by build variants'. Is there a sample. Which plugin to use ?